# Join with uneven columns

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes structured the following way:

|Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type

and

Type|Total # Users|Hour

I'd like to join these columns based on hour however the first dataframe is at a deeper granularity in the second and therefore has more rows. Basically I want a dataframe where I have

|Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type|Total # Users

where the total # users is from the second dataframe. Any suggestions? I think I maybe want to use map?

**Edit:**

Here's an example

DF1

```
|Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type 
|Prod1 |50    |3      |01  |Internet
|Prod2 |10    |2      |07  |iOS
|Prod3 |1     |50     |07  |Internet
|Prod2 |3     |2      |07  |Internet
|Prod3 |8     |2      |05  |Internet
```

DF2

```
|Type    |Total #Users|Hour
|Internet|100         |01
|iOS     |500         |01
|Internet|300         |07
|Internet|15          |05
|iOS     |20          |07
```

Result

```
|Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type    |Total #Users
|Prod1 |50    |3      |01  |Internet|100
|Prod2 |10    |2      |07  |iOS     |20
|Prod3 |1     |50     |07  |Internet|300
|Prod2 |3     |2      |07  |Internet|300
|Prod3 |8     |2      |05  |Internet|15
```

Comment: I don't see any issue. You can join dataframe of different size. Could you be more explicit, like what you currently have and what result you want to get ?

Comment: DF1

|Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type |Prod1|50|3|01|Internet |Prod2|10|2|07|iOS| 20 |Prod3|1|50|07|Internet |Prod2|3|2|07|Internet |Prod3|8|2|05|Internet

DF2 Type|Total # Users|Hour |Internet|100|01 |iOS|500| 01 |Internet|300| 07 |Internet|15| 05 |iOS|20| 07

Result |Source|#Users|#Clicks|Hour|Type|Total Users |Prod1|50|3|01|Internet| 100 |Prod2|10|2|07|iOS| 20 |Prod3|1|50|07|Internet| 300 |Prod2|3|2|07|Internet| 300 |Prod3|8|2|05|Internet| 15

Comment: If the answer fits your needs, could you mark it as accepted ? If not, please give some details on what's wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a left join you're trying to do :

```py
df1.join(df2, (df1.Hour === df2.Hour) & (df1.Type === df2.Type), "left_outer")
```

Short version : a left join keep all the rows from `df1` and join on condition with matching rows of `df2` if there is a match (null if not, duplicate if multiple matches).

[More info on Pyspark join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)
[More info on SQL Joins types](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types)